# On save actions Sublime Text 2

Tags: less, sublimetext2

I am developing websites in Sublime Text 2, I am using LESS and FTP Sync. Problem is that actions of both of plugins are triggered after save. Less is building CSS file and FTP is syncing.

I have 2 problems with that:

1. How can I setup plugins to run one after another? (first LESS and
   then FTP Sync)
2. Generated CSS is not synced (because it wasnt saved by me but by
   plugin). How can I setup FTP Sync to watch for all files.

Answer (score 0):

For the (1) you can delay the upload. Check the line #67 "upload_delay".
For the (2) I don't know, try to create a macro/script.